# Edit all ressource Mailbox settings of all the available ressource mailboxes in Powershell at once

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Quick introduction to my issue:

Our Resource-Mailboxes show the name of the organizer of the meeting instead of the subject.
I found following solution to this problem (Powershell Script)

```
Set-CalendarProcessing -Identity <RESOURCEMAILBOX> -DeleteSubject $False -AddOrganizerToSubject $False
```

This works perfectly so far BUT... is there a way to set this Option for ALL Resourcemailboxes available?

something like...`Set-CalendarProcessing -Identity <*>` ... ?

Thank you for your time.
Cheers
Denis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your Answer. It brought me on the right path of solving this problem:

First i need to get all the Ressource Mailboxes with following script:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited | where {$_.RecipientTypeDetails -eq 'RoomMailbox'}
```

This Code gave me following results:

```
Name                      Alias                ServerName       ProhibitSendQuota                                                     
----                      -----                ----------       -----------------                                                     
Sitzungszimmer 1          Sitzungszimmer1      SRV004           Unlimited                                                             
Aufenthaltsraum           Aufenthaltsraum      SRV004           Unlimited                                                             
Sitzungszimmer EG         SitzungszimmerEG     SRV004           Unlimited                                                             
Produkt- und Erlebnism... pue                  SRV004           Unlimited                                                             
Innovation & Research     innovationresearch   SRV004           Unlimited
```

After this i can just use follwoing script to set the desired options:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited | where {$_.RecipientTypeDetails -eq 'RoomMailbox'} | Set-CalendarProcessing -DeleteSubject $False -AddOrganizerToSubject $False
```

Kind Regards

Denis Faddi

Answer (score 1):

You have to query all Mailboxes and the set the Properties:

```
Get-Mailbox RES* | % { Set-CalendarProcessing -Identity $_ -DeleteSubject $False }
```

If you cannot specify all Resource Mailboxes by name like I did with RES* you could use the -Filter Parameter. But this depends on how you locate the Mailboxes.

Enjoy -tom